# Recognizing image within image in C#

Tags: c#, image, lockbits

I'd like to find an image (*needle*) within an image (*haystack*).

To keep things simple I take two screenshots of my desktop. One full size (*haystack*) and a tiny one (*needle*). I then loop through the haystack image and try to find the needle image.

1. capture needle and haystack screenshot
2. loop through haystack, looking out for haystack[i] == first pixel of needle
3. [if 2. is true:] loop through the 2nd to last pixel of needle and compare it to haystack[i]

Expected result: the needle image is found at the correct location.

I already got it working for some coordinates/widths/heights (A).

But sometimes bits seem to be "off" and therefore **no match is found** (B).

What could I be doing wrong? Any suggestions are welcome. Thanks.

---

```
var needle_height = 25;
var needle_width = 25;
var haystack_height = 400;
var haystack_width = 500;
```

---

**A. example input - match**

```
var needle = screenshot(5, 3, needle_width, needle_height); 
var haystack = screenshot(0, 0, haystack_width, haystack_height);
var result = findmatch(haystack, needle);
```

**B. example input - NO match**

```
var needle = screenshot(5, 5, needle_width, needle_height); 
var haystack = screenshot(0, 0, haystack_width, haystack_height);
var result = findmatch(haystack, needle);
```

---

**1. capture needle and haystack image**

```
private int[] screenshot(int x, int y, int width, int height)
{
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(width, height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
Graphics.FromImage(bmp).CopyFromScreen(x, y, 0, 0, bmp.Size);

var bmd = bmp.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height), 
  ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, bmp.PixelFormat);
var ptr = bmd.Scan0;

var bytes = bmd.Stride * bmp.Height / 4;
var result = new int[bytes];

Marshal.Copy(ptr, result, 0, bytes);
bmp.UnlockBits(bmd);

return result;
}
```

**2. try to find a match**

```
public Point findmatch(int[] haystack, int[] needle)
{
var firstpixel = needle[0];

for (int i = 0; i < haystack.Length; i++)
{
    if (haystack[i] == firstpixel)
    {
    var y = i / haystack_height;
    var x = i % haystack_width;

    var matched = checkmatch(haystack, needle, x, y);
    if (matched)
        return (new Point(x,y));
    }
}    
return new Point();
}
```

**3. verify full match**

```
public bool checkmatch(int[] haystack, int[] needle, int startx, int starty)
{
    for (int y = starty; y < starty + needle_height; y++)
    {
        for (int x = startx; x < startx + needle_width; x++)
        {
            int haystack_index = y * haystack_width + x;
            int needle_index = (y - starty) * needle_width + x - startx;
            if (haystack[haystack_index] != needle[needle_index])
                return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, there is a problem with the `findmatch` loop. You shouldn't just use the haystack image as an array, because you need to subtract needle's width and height from right and bottom respectively:

```
public Point? findmatch(int[] haystack, int[] needle)
{
    var firstpixel = needle[0];

    for (int y = 0; y < haystack_height - needle_height; y++)
        for (int x = 0; x < haystack_width - needle_width; x++)
        {
            if (haystack[y * haystack_width + x] == firstpixel)
            {
                var matched = checkmatch(haystack, needle, x, y);
                if (matched)
                    return (new Point(x, y));
            }
        }

    return null;
}
```

That should probably solve the problem. Also, keep in mind that there might be **multiple matches**. For example, if "needle" is a completely white rectangle portion of a window, there will most likely be many matches in the entire screen. If this is a possibility, modify your `findmatch` method to continue searching for results after the first one is found:

```
public IEnumerable<Point> FindMatches(int[] haystack, int[] needle)
{
    var firstpixel = needle[0];
    for (int y = 0; y < haystack_height - needle_height; y++)
        for (int x = 0; x < haystack_width - needle_width; x++)
        {
            if (haystack[y * haystack_width + x] == firstpixel)
            {
                if (checkmatch(haystack, needle, x, y))
                    yield return (new Point(x, y));
            }
        }
}
```

Next, you need to keep a habit of manually disposing all objects which implement `IDisposable`, which you have created yourself. `Bitmap` and `Graphics` are such objects, meaning that your `screenshot` method needs to be modified to wrap those objects in `using` statements:

```
private int[] screenshot(int x, int y, int width, int height)
{
    // dispose 'bmp' after use
    using (var bmp = new Bitmap(width, height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb))
    {
        // dispose 'g' after use
        using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
        {
            g.CopyFromScreen(x, y, 0, 0, bmp.Size);

            var bmd = bmp.LockBits(
                new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height),
                ImageLockMode.ReadOnly,
                bmp.PixelFormat);

            var ptr = bmd.Scan0;

            // as David pointed out, "bytes" might be
            // a bit misleading name for a length of
            // a 32-bit int array (so I've changed it to "len")

            var len = bmd.Stride * bmp.Height / 4;
            var result = new int[len];
            Marshal.Copy(ptr, result, 0, len);

            bmp.UnlockBits(bmd);

            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

The rest of the code seems ok, with the remark that it won't be very efficient for certain inputs. For example, you might have a large solid color as your desktop's background, which might result in many `checkmatch` calls.

If performance is of interest to you, you might want to check different ways to speed up the search (something like a modified [Rabin-Karp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabin-Karp_string_search_algorithm) comes to mind, but I am sure there are some existing algorithms which ensure that invalid candidates are skipped immediately).

Comment: That did the trick. You, sir, are a true genius. Thank you very much for your help and your effort on how to improve my coding.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of making two screenshots of your desktop with a time interval between them, I would take a screenshot once and cut "needle" and "haystack" from those same bitmap source. Otherwise you have the risk of a change of your desktop contents between the two moments where the screenshots are taken.

EDIT: And when your problem still occurs after that, I would try to save the image to a file and try again with that file using your debugger, giving you a reproducible situation.

Comment: Seems a little silly to say for him to cut out the object from the image which he is attempting to locate.  Chicken/Egg?

Comment: @Druegor: I suspect the screenshot example is just a test case for the OP where he expects a match to be found.

Comment: Hello, Doc Brown. That's a valid suggestion. I thought of that, too, and can assure you that nothing changes this area of the screen. I will try nevertheless.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think your equations for `haystack_index` or `needle_index` are correct.  It looks like you take the `Scan0` offset into account when you copy the bitmap data, but you need to use the bitmap's `Stride` when calculating the byte position.

Also, the `Format32bppArgb` format uses 4 bytes per pixel.  It looks like you are assuming 1 byte per pixel.

Here's the site I used to help with those equations: https://web.archive.org/web/20141229164101/http://bobpowell.net/lockingbits.aspx

> Format32BppArgb: Given X and Y coordinates,  the address of the first element in the
> pixel is Scan0+(y * stride)+(x*4). This Points to the blue byte. The
> following three bytes contain the green, red and alpha bytes.

Comment: I was also confused by the fact that the variable is named `bytes`, and there is a division by 4. But `bytes` is actually the length of an `int` array. So the algorithm compares full RGBA pixels, not individual components.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the [class reference with example code](http://accord-framework.net/docs/html/T_Accord_Imaging_ExhaustiveTemplateMatching.htm) that works great for my C# application for finding needle in haystack for each frame from a USB camera, in year 2018...   I believe Accord is mostly a bunch of C# wrappers for fast C++ code.

Also check out the [C# wrapper for Microsoft C++ DirectShow](http://accord-framework.net/docs/html/N_Accord_Video_DirectShow.htm) that I use to search for needle within each frame from a USB camera